# Having difficulties in understand the flow of middleware when using express.static('public')

Tags: express, middleware

I am learning express now and I have difficulties in understand the flow of middleware in express.
For example, if I have the following code
import express from 'express';

```
const app = express();

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("app.use");
    res.send("hello")
})

app.use(express.static('public'));


app.listen(1234,()=>{
    console.log("started at port:1234");
});
```

I will get the following in the terminal `started at port:1234, app.use` and "hello" in the browser when I type localhost:1234 in my browser. I understand this as the first middleware has the res.send("hello") and therefore it sends back "hello" without passing the res to app.use(express.static('public')) (the public folder has a index.html which is not shown in this case)

but when i modify the code a little bit, I didn't understand the flow of middleware anymore

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("app.use");
    res.send("hello")
})


app.listen(1234,()=>{
    console.log("started at port:1234");
});
```

This time I will get the following in the terminal `started at port:1234 app.use app.use app.use` and the index.html when I type localhost:1234 in my browser.
First, I don't understand why i don't get "hello" in my brower. I understand `app.use(express.static('public'));` But the app.use comes after the `app.use(express.static('public'));` has a res.send("hello") inside it and therefore the request sent back should be "hello" instead of index.html?
Secondly, why does the terminal shown "app.use" more then one time? `app.use((req,res,next)=>{console.log("app.use");res.send("hello")})` should only be executed one time only? Not to mention it has a res.send inside it .
Can anyone please explain this to me please? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

the order in which middleware are define matter, when the first middleware in the stack of middleware match the request path, it will be responsible for handleling the Request.

I'll give and example

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('First middleware');
});
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Second middleware');
}
```

As you can see both middleware have the same path. the first request handler in the stack of middleware will be exectued when the request URL is `http://localhost:[port_number]/` and the second will not be executed.

Generaly when you navigate to the root path of any website at the backend side the server will look for a file named `index.html`, that is the default configuration for many web server. So as the directory in which there are all static files served by express contain a file named `index.html` when you navigate to the root Path of you express app which `express.static` middleware attached before your personalized middleware like bellow.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("app.use");
    res.send("hello")
})
```

The `index.html` file which is inside of the `public` directory will be rendered instead of `hello`.